# javascript scrollable input

Tags: angularjs, mobile, scrollable, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on a mobile web app using Angularjs and on one page I have a list of fields such as a date which I want the user to be able to click on and edit using separate scrollable lists, similarly to what can be seen here:

http://ionicframework.com/html5-input-types/#month

What's the simplest way of achieving this just with using HTML, CSS and Angular (or any javascript really)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<input type="date"/>
```

On iphones it will have the same effect and on androids its similar but not exactly the same.

If you want to have a scrollable list, simply use

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

to achieve this

Comment: This is what I'm doing currently but I'd prefer a way that's visually consistent between editing dates and other fields across different devices if possible.